# Filtering out polygons that consists of less than 3 nodes

Tags: postgis

I have OSM data stored in PostGIS.

After running the following query:

```
select st_astext(st_forcepolygonccw(st_transform(geom,32633))), st_geometrytype(geom) from osm_versions.polygon_v1
limit 10
```

I get [this result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxTCE.png).

As you may see only 2 out of 10 spatial objects consist of more than 1 node yet all of them have GeometryType *ST_Polygon*. As a polygon is "*a plane figure that is described by a finite number of straight line segments connected to form a closed polygonal chain*" (after [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Polygon)) I have no use for "polygons" with less than 3 nodes.

My questions are:
Is there any command that returns, given a set of geometries, a subset of geometries that consists of more than 2 nodes?
How should I proceed in order to filter out "polygons" with less than 3 nodes?

As for the question how come that points are counted as polygons, I have no idea as the data were provided by an external source.

Comment: Your premise is flawed. A polygon geometry is defined by *four* vertices (the last must be identical to the first).

Comment: I know, yet I have "polygons" with 1 node. And I got a problem. If my question are badly formulated, then please, do feel free to reformulate them and edit my post. 

As for the "3 nodes" I forgot about the "closing node", but it should have no practical consequences as points consists of 1 node, lines of 2 and polygons, as you said, of al least 4, thus 4 is the only number in this context that islarger than 3.

Comment: Select the ones having ST_IsValid='true'. OSM has also invalid polygons which have enough vertices but no area because the vertices are along a line.

Comment: Thanks, would you mind writing an answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter out polygons with too few vertices and also geometries which are invalid for any other reason with a PostGIS function [ST_IsValid](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_IsValid.html)

OSM data often contains for example polygons which have enough vertices but no area because the vertices are located along a line.